# One random item per day from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using javascript array to randomly select source for video player. Everytime I refresh the window it randomly chooses another source from the array to play (which is I guess 'window.onload'). Instead, I want it to choose 1 source, randomly, every day at certain time (lets say 9 PM), and stick with it until next one is chosen following day.

I tried using some methods for setting date I found here, but nothing works without messing with the current script. I would appreaciate if someone could help me maintain current function, but make it daily.

```js
const srcArray = [
    "source1",
    "source2",
    "source3"
];

const source = document.querySelector("video");

window.onload = () => generateRandomSrc(srcArray);

function generateRandomSrc(array){
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length); 
    source.setAttribute("src", array[randomNum]);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the date and time of the last visitor access from that client and then compare that time to see if it is time to generate a new random result.

Comment: Do you want all visitors to see the same "random" video every day? Or should every visitor get a different random video every day?

Comment: Video should be same for every user. Like a "Video of the Day" feature, which refreshes every day

Comment: @nickberckley then you'd need a server-side script to pick the video. That can't be done client-side.

Comment: How would I do it from client-side (every user sees different 'random' video) but daily? That would also help me, I'm mostly interested in learning about timing function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Math.random` which will be differ in each run in each client, Generate random index based on `day`, `month`, and `year`. (This should same valid index when you run on same day)

```js
const srcArray = [
    "source1",
    "source2",
    "source3"
];

const source = document.querySelector("#video");

window.onload = () => generateRandomSrc(srcArray);

const random = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  return (date.getFullYear() * date.getDate() * (date.getMonth() + 1)) % srcArray.length;
}

function generateRandomSrc(array) {
    source.innerText = `Today's video ${srcArray[random()]}`
}
```

```html
<div id="video"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use date function, `new Date().getDay()` day of week (7) or `new Date().getDate()` (28-31)

```js
const srcArray = [
    "source1",
    "source2",
    "source3",
    "source4",
    "source5",
    "source6",
    "source7"
];

const source = document.querySelector("video");

window.onload = () => generateRandomSrc(srcArray);
function generateRandomSrc(array){
    const today = new Date().getDay();
    console.log("today video is:", srcArray[today])
}
```

Comment: I did some tweaks on this code and think made it work. I will be running tests today and tomorrow to observe pattern of change in sources, fingers crossed it works